# Best way to fourier transform

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, core-audio

We need to get constantly- audio pure frequencies to the iPhone audio jack mic input, and recognize specific frequency.

i have read about 2 ways of FFT(/fourier transform) : AurioTouch , or using Accelerate framework. i also found a tutorial on recognize a blow-which I couldn't understand if it works only on the mic, or also from the mic input jack? (same?)

The apple AurioTouch seems so big and heavy, and as far as I know from University, the math of the Fourier is just a sigma of exponents -sampled.

What is the best way for me to implement this? the easiest way?
I cant understand something from the Apple documentation, it's full of files and code, and no one direct you on exactly step by step how to do that.(what each file does? ccp files?!)

Something else, what's the best way to recognize a short on the audio jack, as the Apple headphones switches does ?

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Have you found an answer?

Comment: no...no one helped me....just dont have any idea..

Answer (score 1):

Definitely use the FFT functions provided by Accelerate framework because this is the most highly optimized framework on iPhone for doing massively parallel vector arithmetic.

Comment: Yep!  accelerate framework's FFT is blindingly fast and uses practically 0% CPU.  AurioTouch is a PoS, and to be avoided.